# Action Bar not updated when updating language

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am currently building an app where I allow people updating the language within the application. But when changing the locale, all strings get updated but not the one in the action bar (corresponding to the activity name in the manifest). The language change is only taken into consideration when the app is restarted from scratch. What would be the best way to get all action bars updated without forcing an app reboot ?

Thanks in advance for your time and help on this one.
Cheers,

Benjamin

Comment: The simpliest solution is to restart your application after you set the new Locale.

Comment: I would use the same app name for every language... After all, `Angry Birds` is not translated in any language! It's `Angry Birds` in all languages. And it's enough. Otherwise, you'd tend to **confuse your users**.

Comment: Hey Frank. Sorry this was unclear in my comment. I agree for the main activity displaying the application name (which I indeed do not plan to translate) but it is different case with the other activities (notably the one dedicated to 'Settings' or some other part of the flow).

Comment: Did you solve this? I noticed that actionbar menu items also retain the old names. I'm using the new Toolbar.

Comment: @Ben You solve it yet? Please tell your solution. I got the same problem too.

Comment: Should we have to restart app again?