# How to update ActionBar after change language in PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, locale, preferencefragment

I want to update language in app by click on the *preference* in setting fragment which I use preference fragment. Successfully, I can update almost everything in app after change language except `ActionBar` in each activity including the setting fragment. The only solution I know is to restart app.

Again, I want to change app language include *ActionBar* after click change in setting. Is it possible?

I have search [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26240760/5241603), but not solve yet. Here is my setting layout.

[image]

Please help. Thank

Comment: One more thing, the actionbar not change if I don't clear the app from recent app.

Comment: Sending broadcast message can solve your issue. Than you can set new title as per selected change in `onReceive()` of your `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: @astuter No, I want to change language of titlebar not set new titlebar.

Comment: Are you using configChanges? Paste required code for java and xml both.

Comment: I solved my issue, and answer on another thread. Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39970565/5241603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution:

App won't change Actionbar language after change locale. I won't refresh it. It will change when I remove app from the recent app which make the app completely close.

To solve:

1. I use `setTitle(R.id.myapplabel)` when you want to refresh app or
   **oncreate**, so no need to restart app.
2. Translate activity label on **string.xml** and it works.