# Why does android:label's text not changing when user changes language within my app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, locale, onconfigurationchanged

So within my app, the very first Activity that user sees is to choose language.

Lets say if user chooses french and then goes to ActivityB, then to ActivityC.

Now decides to changes language.

So goes back to ActivityB and then to very first Activity and choses language as Spanish.

Now again when user goes to ActivityB, all other text within the fragment/activity is changed to Spanish, but android:label still remains in French. how to fix this?

This is how my ActivityA looks

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_language, container, false);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lang_choice_radio);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.english_lang:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        setLocale("en_US");
                        Intent intentEng = new Intent(getActivity(), Choose_Country.class);
                        startActivity(intentEng);
                        break;

                    case R.id.indonesian_lang:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        setLocale("in");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Choose_Country.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        onConfigurationChanged(conf);
        Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChooseLanguage.class); // refresh the activity
        refreshIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        refreshIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(refreshIntent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Comment: add <label> string to your corresponding language string files and use a string reference. Example{android:label="@string/label"} It will help you.

Comment: That is how it is already in place.

Comment: You are finishing the activity on this line getActivity().finish(); then how can user navigate back[From Activity B] to this activity[A] ?

Comment: Step 1: ActivityA (choose French) --> ActivityB --> ActivityC .
Step 2: ActivityC --> ActivityB --> ActivityA
Step 3: ActivityA (choose Spanish) --> ActivityB --> ActivityC. Now all text in ActivtyB and C are in Spanish. But titles in ActivityB and ActivityC (which uses text from strings.xml ) . 

Above code is of ActivityA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, app won't change Actionbar language after change locale. It will change when I remove app from the recent app which make the app completely close. To solve, I use `setTitle(R.id.myapplabel)` when you want to refresh app or **oncreate**, so no need to restart app. Translate your activity label on string.xml and it should works.

Comment: Now I have another issue. After choosing French in ActivityA , I go to ActivityB and I see everything in French. But if I rotate my phone, the entire fragment turns into English (which is the default). I searched Stackoverflow answers like using android:confgChanges="orientation|keyboard|locale". But it doesn't work.

Comment: When you rotate the screen, your app restart again. So to handle this, you have to put your setLocale method and than setTitle to your activity label in oncreate

Answer (score -1):

Few steps to solve the problem.

1. Move your app to ToolBar no more ActionBar
2. Remove label from AndroidManifest.xml file

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".package.Activity"
       android:label=""
       android:configChanges="locale"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" />
   ```
3. Recreate your app when change locale activity.recreate()
4. All activity title should be in strings.xml file

Comment: this is not a solution to the prolem, it only prevents it from happening that much.

Comment: We have already write the logic to change the locale , after this our activities titles is not changed. so i just follow this approach and got the solution. If you have any better solutions than please share. @Shark